# What is the biblical basis that eternity involves no change?

Tags: biblical-basis, eternity

What is the Biblical basis for eternity lacking change? i.e, that God is immutable and views all time simultaneously.

Boethius defines eternity as "simultaneously full and perfect possession of interminable life"

What parts of the Bible support this understanding?